# How to re-project a netcdf file?

Tags: gdalwarp, netcdf

I want to re-project and resample a netcf file but I am getting a usage problem:

```
gdalwarp  -t_srs EPSG:3410 -ts 1383 586 NETCFD:"C:\data\product.nc":gsfc output.tiff
```

Comment: Can you tell us what the source CRS of the netcdf file is or maybe where you obtained it?

Comment: I do not know what is the CRS of it.

Comment: I'm sure it is documented somewhere. We could help you look for it if you tell us where the dataset is from.

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing your usage problem comes from using `-outsize`, which is for `gdal_translate`. With `gdalwarp` you want to use the `-ts` option.

Here's the command line that worked for me. Note that you can also specifiy the target SRS with a PROj4 code instead of an EPSG code.

```
gdalwarp  -t_srs "+proj=cea +lon_0=0 +lat_ts=30 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6371228 +b=6371228 +units=m +no_defs " -ts 1383 586 product.nc output.tif

Creating output file that is 1383P x 586L.
Processing input file product.nc.
Using internal nodata values (e.g. 1e+015) for image product.nc.
Copying nodata values from source product.nc to destination output.tif.
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
```

I'd also suggest taking a look into the `-r` option, which gives you more control over the resampling method used. Right now it just uses the default *nearest neighbour* algorithm.

edit as per @AndreJ s comment:

This will only work if the source CRS is contained in the product.nc If it is not you'll need to manually set it with `-s_srs`.

Comment: `gdalinfo -proj4 -nomd output.tif` reports this to be `+proj=cea +lon_0=0 +lat_ts=30 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6371228 +b=6371228 +units=m +no_defs ` which is the [PROJ4 code for EPSG:3410](http://www.spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/3410/).

Comment: Since the file has no CRS information, -t_srs will not work unless you set the source CRS too with -s_srs.

Comment: @AndreJ Absolutely right. I totally missed the missing CRS in the input file.

Answer (score 2):

It works for me with this syntax:

```
gdalwarp  -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:3410 -ts 1383 586 -wo SOURCE_EXTRA=1000 product.nc output.tiff
```

In your example, you are requesting a subdataset, but the file contains bands, not subdatasets. You can extract bands with gdal_transform -b.

The SOURCE_EXTRA option sanitizes artefacts around the date line.

Comment: But if look at output map, you would see a clear "cut" as edge on the top  and bottom right  which cut parts of newzealand.

Comment: How did you infer the source CRS to be EPSG:4326?

Comment: @Kersten from the corner coordinates of around +/- 180/90. It could be a sphere as well.

Comment: @AndreJ have you looked at the edges?

Comment: See my extended answer. It should look better now.

Comment: that worked fine.