# Dateline disappears after clipping shapefile to hemisphere?

Tags: qgis, vector, coordinate-system

I am working with [this](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-physical-vectors/10m-geographic-lines/) natural earth shapefile. The dateline disappears after using the mentioned [clip to hemisphere plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/ClipToHemisphere/). Densifying the geometry does not help.

Weird to me seems that clipping to a hemisphere centered at lat -76,98267 / lon -163,36119 works just fine (dateline present after clip) while after clipping to a center at lat 26,50588 / lon -171,82873 the dateline dissaperes although it should be visible.

**Solved** as noticed in the comments  by @Jake a bug in the [clip to hemisphere plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/ClipToHemisphere/) is the problem. I quickfixed it and its all good now.

Comment: Have you tried the Vector > Data Management > Define Current Projection tool? There is also a "Reproject Layer" tool in the Processing toolbox.

Comment: Possibly try densifying the geometries.

Comment: If the reported failed values are in radians, they're either approximately 30, -13.5 or the reverse (not sure which is latitude). It's probably lat=-13.5 lon=30,  which is very, very close to the "horizon"/hemisphere edge. (This assumes center is -77, -163).

Comment: @AndreJ: Using decimal points instead of commas fixed the problem when I tried to reproduce the error. Note that removing the features from the rear of the view is what the [ClipToHemisphere-Plugin](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/78346/ortho-projection-produces-artifacts) does (which simooooon used in step 1).

Comment: @simooooon: Does densifying the geometry (using Vector / Geometry Tools / Densify Geometries) as suggested by mkennedy solve the problem with the disappearing dateline? If not, could you edit your question to describe the problem in more detail?

Comment: For the dateline issue, you might take a look at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/165290/how-to-re-project-a-netcdf-file/165293#165293

Comment: This is a bug in the Clip to Hemisphere plugin (I've opened a [ticket](https://github.com/jdugge/ClipToHemisphere/blob/master/ClipToHemisphere.py#L264)). As a quick fix, you can change the `180` in https://github.com/jdugge/ClipToHemisphere/blob/master/ClipToHemisphere.py#L264 to `180.1` in your local copy of the plugin (in `.qgis2\python\plugins\ClipToHemisphere` in your home directory), then restart QGIS. I'll fix the error and upload a new version of the plugin on the weekend.

Comment: This is now fixed and the [corrected version of the plugin](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/ClipToHemisphere/version/0.2/) is available in the QGIS plugin repository.